# Continue timer when iOS app is terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

How can I continue running my timer when my app is terminated from multitasking?

My timer continues normally when app is closed then re-opened but when it is terminated the timer continues to run but doesn't account for the time since the app was killed.

My timer Looks like this :

```
-(void)beginTimer {
//hide/unhide stuff
punchIn.hidden = 1;
hhmmssLabel.hidden = 0;
punchOut.hidden = 0;
breakTime.hidden = 0;

hhmmssLabel.text = @"00:00:00";


//timer function
[self unPauseTimer];

pauseTimeInterval = 0;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:timerIsRunning = YES forKey:@"running"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:onBreak = NO forKey:@"break"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:pauseTimeInterval forKey:@"pausedTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}
-(void)endTimer {
//hide/unhide stuff
punchIn.hidden = 0;
hhmmssLabel.hidden = 1;
punchOut.hidden = 1;
breakTime.hidden = 1;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:timerIsRunning = NO forKey:@"running"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//timer function
[self pausedTimer];

[self addToPlist];

second = 0;
pauseTimeInterval = 0;

}

//timer method from RMD
-(void) updateTimer {

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
second = (NSUInteger)round(timeInterval);
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lu:%02lu:%02lu",
                    second / 3600, (second / 60) % 60, second % 60];
hhmmssLabel.text = string;
pauseTimeInterval = timeInterval;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:pauseTimeInterval forKey:@"pausedTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}
-(void)pausedTimer {

[tickerTimer invalidate];
tickerTimer = nil;
}

-(void) unPauseTimer {

startDate = [NSDate date];
startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(pauseTimeInterval))];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:startDate forKey:@"startDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
tickerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

In my appDelegate i have this:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

[[ViewController sharedLayer] saveDataOnKill];
}
```

which calls this:

```
-(void)saveDataOnKill {

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:timerIsRunning = YES forKey:@"running"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:onBreak = NO forKey:@"break"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:pauseTimeInterval forKey:@"pausedTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

I know somehow the timer knows where it left off and continues but it doesn't account for the time since the app has been killed.

Comment: FYI - there is no need to call `synchronize` so much. In fact, just call it once in your app delegate when the app goes to the background.

Comment: FYI - `applicationWillTerminate:` is almost never called for most apps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on synchronize, but is anything called when the app is deleted from multitasking

Comment: No. When your app is killed, it gets no notification of any kind. Save all state when the app goes to the background incase it is terminated while in the background.

Comment: Okay, thanks i'll try something with that

Comment: Not making any difference